# How to check if a firebase document exists or not?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app for booking.
At the booking history page if the user hasn't booked yet it should be like this:

[image: Booking History page]

However when I execute it, It is like this:

[image: it is like this]

The FireStore Database Image:
[image: the collection doesn't exists]

The code:

```
 DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("Booking").document(userID);
    //if the document exists then set text and make visible, but if it doesn't exist dont be visible
    //i am a beginner i set this if condition it doesn't seem to work it just sets the textviews to visible please help.
    if(documentReference!=null) {
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                //putting if else fixed crashing
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d("Tag", "Error:" + e.getMessage());
                } else {
                    //pickup
                    mYourpickup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mYourdestination.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mBook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mFirstnamelastname.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("a1 - Fullname"));
                    mFirstnamelastname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mMobnum.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("a2 - PhoneNo"));
                    mMobnum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mPincode.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("a3 - Pincode"));
                    mPincode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mFlatno.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("a4 - Flatno"));
                    mFlatno.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mArea.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("a5 - Area"));
                    mArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mLandmark.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("a6 - Landmark"));
                    mLandmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mTown.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("a7 - Town"));
                    mTown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mState.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("a8 - State"));
                    mState.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //destination
                    mFirstnamelastname2.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("d1 - Fullname2"));
                    mFirstnamelastname2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mMobnum2.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("d2 - PhoneNo2"));
                    mMobnum2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mPincode2.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("d3 - Pincode2"));
                    mPincode2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mFlatno2.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("d4 - Flatno2"));
                    mFlatno2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mArea2.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("d5 - Area"));
                    mArea2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mLandmark2.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("d6 - Landmark2"));
                    mLandmark2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mTown2.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("d7 - Town2"));
                    mTown2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mState2.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("d8 - State2"));
                    mState2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Please when you reply to this question try to explain me what is happening so that I learn and understand instead of copy pasting.
Thank You :)

Comment: Well, documentSnapshot is nullable, so that should tell you if that snapshot exists or not. Otherwise, what if you check when documentReference==null?

Comment: Can you please explain how? if you could edit the code i can understand better i am a bit slow to understand. thanks :)

Comment: You have two variables. `documentSnapshot` and `documentReference`. Both are allowed to be null. If they are, then the data they refer to does not exist. Also `fstore.collection("Booking")` alone should likely throw an exception if that collection does not exist

Comment: I tried documentReference==null didn't work also tried with documentSnapshot didn't work either please help

Comment: I think you should show where `"a1 - Fullname"` exists in your database because your code appears not to match your images

Comment: So when the collection is created from the booking page: https://imgur.com/ljxbUBJ.png      and the data is fetched: https://imgur.com/wEVO5sy.png

Comment: Okay, so the booking collection does exist... Then what database instance are you connected to in your original image?

Comment: the booking collection exists only when  user books something,then the booking history page fetches and sets the text, what is want is when a user visits the booking history without actually booking something. it should be blank. and the collection wouldn't exist then, so it should set visibility to invisible

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then either `fstore.collection("Booking")` returns null, or maybe throws an exception

Comment: can you please give an if condition to check f.store.collection("Booking") returns null and then i do my statements. sorry if im wasting your time :(

Comment: Just extract the variables `CollectionReference c = fstore.collection("Booking")`...`if (c!=null) { DocumentReference documentReference = c.document(userID);`

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working can we please discuss this somewhere else ? i would like to show u the code .